# What Is the Code for One-Liner Arrow Functions That Do Not Return Any Value?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am looking for a way to code one-liner arrow functions that do not return any value. For example:

```
    const fun = x => {
      console.log(x);
    };
```

I would remove the curly braces. Is it possible?

Comment: const fun = x => x;
console.log(fun(1));

Comment: `const fun = x => ...` will return whatever `...` returns. So if `...` is a `console.log` which returns `void`, also `fun` will return `void`

Comment: Numbers of lines really is just the result of formatters and prettifiers, just put everything in a single line and you a one-liner...

Comment: FYI if you don't explicitly return a value, the function will implicitly return `undefined`. Since `console.log()` returns undefined, your example is exactly the same with or without the braces.

Comment: `const a = () => void 0`

Comment: *"I would remove the curly braces. Is it possible?"*: are you saying you didn't try yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the `void` operator

This can be used if you want to run side effect without returning the value

For example:

```js
const sideEffectAndReturn = () => {
  console.log('side effect')

  return 10
}

const voidFunc = () => void sideEffectAndReturn()

const returnValue = voidFunc()

console.log({
  returnValue
})
```

`voidFunc` will always return `undefined` and the side effect will still be called without the curly braces

Answer (score 0):

**without curly braces it will be return the value**

```js
const fun = x => x;
console.log(fun(1));
```

**with curly brace need to add return**

```
const fun1 = x => {
  return x;
};
console.log(fun1(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just remove the braces, since `console.log` does not return anything itself:

```
const fun = x => console.log(x);
```

The result is `undefined`, just as with the braces and no `return` statement.

If you have a single-expression body whose result value you want to suppress, you can also use the [`void` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void):

```
const fun = x => void console.log(x);
```